# Putting code chunk in an if statement changes assigning behavior R

Tags: r, list, if-statement, assign

I'm running into a very curious R issue. I have a chunk of code within an `if` statement that's assigning list elements, but that reacts differently whether it's run within the `if` statement (even if the if statement is `if (1==1) {...}`) or outside of it.

Basically, the code *should* just be doing `if (true) {Raw[[1]]$params=params[[1]]; Raw[[2]]$params=params[[2]]; etc..}`, but in the end, `Raw[[1]]$params==Raw[[2]]$params` and `Raw[[3]]$params==Raw[[4]]$params`, but *only* if it's in the `if (true) {}` statement. It works fine if it's not inside an `if` statement.

Let me show an example (this is a greatly simplified version of the original code; the motivation for the `rep` and the list assigning is for variable management reasons not relevant to the issue):

```
#----- Create variables
# params is a 4-element list
params0 <- list(runif(2),runif(4),runif(6),runif(8))
# Raw is a 2-element list, of which every element is another (named) list
Raw0 <- list(list(data=runif(3),params=runif(2)),
             list(data=runif(6),params=runif(6)))

dothing <- TRUE

#----- With if statement - does not correctly assign
Raw <- Raw0
params <- params0

if (dothing) {
  Raw <- rep(Raw,each=2)
  for (x in seq(1,length(params))) {
    Raw[[x]]$params <- params[[x]]
  }
}

# This should be false since params[[1]] ~= params[[2]], but returns true 
identical(Raw[[1]],Raw[[2]])

#----- Without if statement - does correctly assign
Raw <- Raw0
params <- params0

Raw <- rep(Raw,each=2)
for (x in seq(1,length(params))) {
  Raw[[x]]$params <- params[[x]]
}

# This returns false as expected
identical(Raw[[1]],Raw[[2]])
```

A final, very strange wrinkle in all this - in the original code, the assigning works fine if the code is run chunk-by-chunk (without missing any line), but does not correctly assign if the whole code is run at once.

Would anyone be able to tell me what I'm missing here? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: (What IDE are you using?) When I run your first chunk (through `dothing <- TRUE`), and then run the second chunk (with `if`), I get `FALSE` instead. When I run source chunks together as one, I get `TRUE` as you do. I'm doing this in emacs/ess, so it might be something to do with chunk ordering and visibility of variables. Interesting.

Comment: I'm using RStudio - yeah, I thought it might've originally been an issue in transferring over commands from SublimeText, but then I rewrote at least this chunk natively in RStudio with the same issue

hmm...

Comment: Run your code again replacing `Raw <- rep(Raw,each=2)` with `assign('Raw', rep(Raw, each=2))`. I believe R is assigning your data inside the `for loop` to a cached environment and then losing it when returning to `R_GlobalEnv`. So in `identical(Raw[[1]],Raw[[2]])` the `Raw` variable that is really being compared is from `Raw <- rep(Raw,each=2)`.

Comment: That definitely works, thank you for the fix! I am very curious as to why this would be affected by the `if` statement, or be dependent on whether it's run as a chunk or a whole code... Does `if` create its own environment in R?

Comment: Further ... if you do *something* with (not "to") `Raw` before the loop starts (e.g., `str(Raw)` immediately before `if`) it now works as expected. That suggests it is not necessarily (or "just") the `{ }` environment (though that still may be part of it). (It appears to be something specific ... `invisible(Raw)` or `Raw` instead of `str(Raw)` does *not* work, `head(Raw)` *does*.)

Comment: @r2evans It maybe that by doing something to `Raw`, that is not temporary, before the loop starts forces R to bring `Raw` into the current environment. Perhaps, running a loop on a cached variable will only return that variable to its originally location?

Comment: Another wrinkle - when I was testing this around and trying to see where the wrong assignment was happening, it turns out that `Raw[[1]]` is incorrectly assigned when `x = 2`. So it's still correct when `x = 1`, but then `Raw[[1]]` changes once the `Raw[[x]]$params <- params[[x]]` line is run with `x=2`

Comment: This also happens when I just did
`Raw[[1]]$params <- params[[1]]`
`Raw[[2]]$params <- params[[2]]`, etc. explicitly

Comment: You are not accessing the list correctly, the length and parameters of the list assigned is different

Comment: Hi @user1653941, thanks for the response; could you clarify what you mean by the length and parameters of the list assigned being different?

Comment: For eg ,  try Raw[[x]][2] in your code, then you will see a warning. Raw[[1]]["params"] returns a list while the Raw[[1]]$params or Raw[[1]][[2]] returns the content. So the replacement is not correct - its not a multiple of replacement length.

Comment: @ks905383 did that solve your problem ,where you looking for something else ?

Comment: Thank you for the response - I think I understand the issue as it pertains to the example code above. I'm still confused about a few things though: 1) why is there different behavior based on whether the code is sourced or run separately? 2) If it's nothing with the `if` statement, then why do the two halves of the code give different answers above. I might change the example code based on your comments though - in the full version in my code, the params elements are actually all the same length - I just made them different here to make it easier to distinguish them. :/

Comment: To clarify - both user1653941 and avenger012 's suggestions are definitely valid as workarounds, and my code works fine now, but I'm just still trying to figure out *why* this is happening to avoid it in the future

Answer (score 1):

The observed behavior has nothing to do with the `if` loop.
If you assign different structures it will throw a warning "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".
I dont think it did - in your case when - `Raw` content is accessed using `$` and replaced with contents of `params`.

```
> str(Raw[[1]]$params)
 num [1:2] 0.925 0.393
> str(params[[1]])
 num [1:2] 0.177 0.986

#returns the content
> str(Raw[[1]]$params)  #Used in your eg
 num [1:2] 0.949 0.143
> str(Raw[[1]][[2]])    #Equivalent to the one used in your eg
 num [1:2] 0.949 0.143

#returns the type of list 
> str(Raw[[1]]["params"])
List of 1
 $ params: num [1:2] 0.949 0.143
```

The difference is `Raw[[1]]["params"]` returns a `list` while the `Raw[[1]]$params` or `Raw[[1]][[2]]` returns the content.

But actually, this would have worked when a list of same size and type is replaced with another list (which is a correct multiple of replacement length).

**Updated code:**

```
#----- Create variables
# params is a 4-element list
params0 <- list(runif(2),runif(4),runif(6),runif(8))
# Raw is a 2-element list, of which every element is another (named) list
Raw0 <- list(list(data=runif(3),params=runif(2)),
             list(data=runif(6),params=runif(6)))

dothing <- TRUE

#----- With if statement - does not correctly assign
Raw <- Raw0
params <- params0

if (dothing) {
  Raw <- rep(Raw,each=2)
  for (x in seq(1,length(params))) {
    Raw[[x]]["params"] <- params[x]      ##Note the way list is returned and list is replaced for another list.
  }
}

#CORRECTED returns false: This should be false since params[[1]] ~= params[[2]], but returns true
identical(Raw[[1]],Raw[[2]])
```